# jQuery radio button group check

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, radio-button

I use this piece of jQuery code to check if a group of radio buttons is checked.

jQuery code :

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {  

    $("#offerteaanvragen").submit(function(event) {
        var className = $('.stap2titel').attr('class');
        if (className == "stap2titel") {

        if (!$("input[name='color']").is(':checked')) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var para = document.createTextNode("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Selecteer een kleur");
           var element = document.getElementById("error_kleur");
           element.appendChild(para);
         }
 });
```

The top side of the code is to check if I am on the correct page by checking the (h5) title, and if I am in the correct form. Then I check my group of input buttons with the same name. If 1 of them is checked it should skip the code, But it does always say it is not checked.

Here is the how the input looks like:

```
<input id="color2" class="input_hidden" type="radio" value="color2" name="color">
```

These are generated by code because the amount of inputs can change on the available colors.

How do I fix this?

PS: This is code that is for IE only.

EDIT: I think it is something with the IF statement. It will always return True. Should I delete the ! in the IF statement and then paste the code in the else statement ? This would cause the if statement to execute the code in the else if checkbox selected == false.

Comment: You use `$("input[name='kleur']")` in your JS, but `name="color"` in your HTML

Comment: And `var className = $('.stap2titel').attr('class'); if (className == "stap2titel") {` will always return true, because `$('.stap2titel')` selects all elements with the class `.stap2titel`.

Comment: The className is to check if a title with that class name exists on the page. If it not exist it should return false which works. and it returns true if on the corresponding page. That is not the problem. The problem is that if (!$("input[name='color']").is(':checked')) { always returns true even if 1 of the inputs is checked.

Comment: Then better use: `if( $('.stap2titel').length > 0){` :)

Comment: Yeh I did not think of that, Only started with jQuery 2 days ago. But the problems lies in the IF statment that check the CHECKED factor on radio buttons with the same name.

Comment: No problem, we all need to learn :). What if you use this for your if-statement `if( $("input[name='color']:checked").length>0 )`